# Core Data: Merging children added on a background context is funky

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa, core-data, nsoperation

### Background

- Multi threaded Core Data application
- `NSTreeController` and `NSOutlineView` with bindings
- Creates children objects in an NSOperation on a background context
- Merges into main context using `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification`

[image: Data Model]

### Problem

- If I queue 20 children creation operations up, once the merges have completed, I see only about 10-15 child objects in the outline view.
- If I set the max concurrent operations to 1, it works perfectly and I see 20 children.

### Question

Is what I'm trying to do impossible? I can see how core data might struggle to do the merges successfully. Or is there an issue with my code?

### Code

**JGGroupController**

```
 -(id)init {
     self = [super init];
     queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
     [queue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:10]; // If this is 1, it works like a dream. Anything higher and it bombs.
     return self;
 }

 -(IBAction)addTrainingEntryChild:(id)sender {
     moc  = [[NSApp delegate] managedObjectContext];
     JGTrainingBase *groupToAddTo = [[tree selectedObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
     for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
         JGAddChildrenObjectOperation    *addOperation = [[JGAddChildrenObjectOperation alloc] init]; 
         [addOperation addChildObjectToGroup:[groupToAddTo objectID]];
         [queue addOperation:addOperation];
     }
 }
```

**JGAddChildrenObjectOperation - NSOperation subclass**

```
 -(id)addChildObjectToGroup:(NSManagedObjectID *)groupToAddToID_ {
     groupToAddToObjectID = groupToAddToID_;
     return self;
 }

 -(void)main {
     [self startOperation];
     JGTrainingBase *groupToAddTo    = (JGTrainingBase *)[imoc objectWithID:groupToAddToObjectID];
     JGTrainingBase *entryChildToAdd = [JGTrainingBase insertInManagedObjectContext:imoc];
     [groupToAddTo addChildren:[NSSet setWithObject:entryChildToAdd]];
     [imoc save];
 [self cleanup];
     [self finishOperation];
 }

 -(void)mergeChanges:(NSNotification *)notification {
     NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = [[NSApp delegate] managedObjectContext];
     [mainContext performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:)
                                   withObject:notification
                                waitUntilDone:YES];  
 }


 -(void)startOperation {
            // Omitted - Manage isExecuting, isPaused, isFinished etc flags

     imoc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
     [imoc setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[[NSApp delegate] persistentStoreCoordinator]];
     [imoc setUndoManager:nil];
     [imoc setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy];
     [imoc setStalenessInterval:0];

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                              selector:@selector(mergeChanges:) 
                                                  name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification 
                                                object:imoc];
 }

 -(void)finishOperation {
            // Omitted - Manage isExecuting, isPaused, isFinished etc flags
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your operations are using different "versions" of the entity from the store.  Consider this order of operations:

You create 2 operations, let's call them O:F and O:G which are to add children F and G to group 1, noted as G:1 with a children entry set [A,B,C,D,E].

The operation queue dequeues O:F and O:G at the same time, thus they both fetch a managed object context and entity G:1.

O:F sets children of G:1 to [A,B,C,D,E,F].
O:G sets children of G:2 to [A,B,C,D,E,G].

It doesn't matter which operation wins, you will end up with either [A,B,C,D,E,F] or [A,B,C,D,E,G], both of which are incorrect values in the store.

I believe CoreData should be throwing an optimistic locking error in one of those threads though, as it's changes would be out of date.  But I could be wrong.

The bottom line is you're mutating the same object across threads without synchronizing the state of the object.  Instead of creating 20 operations create 1 operation which adds 20 objects, but you have a core architectural problem of trying to mutate the same object from multiple threads without synchronization.

That will fail every time.

Comment: Thanks for another excellent and very clear answer. I suspected it would be something like this, but as you suggest, I expected Core Data to throw an optimistic locking exception. It seems pretty obvious (again) now you've explained what's going on. The bottom line seems to be that this is not possible. I'm assuming @synchronised wouldn't help because the managed object isn't at the same address as the same object in another thread - they're both on separate contexts.

Comment: Yeah you would have to set up some kind of global NSLock or pthread lock to synchronize the threads.  This locking scheme as you can imagine gets very tricky. I think one thing you should be careful of is using threads at all in this case.  Unless your objects have a very costly instantiation cost this optimization might be premature, and you could save yourself a lot of headaches by keeping the grunt work isolated to the main thread.

Comment: This was in an experimental project to explore how to merge transient attributes in, but in my main project I have spent a lot of time moving operations into a background thread. I wish I'd taken heed of Matt Gallagher's advice to optimise everything I could about my main thread approach before moving stuff into a background thread. I think all this effort might have been wasted.